# Use ManyToOne relation as multiple choice in Symfony Form (with Doctrine)

Tags: symfony, one-to-many, symfony-forms, many-to-one

Say, there is a simple many-to-one relations: Model has hair type and eyes color:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Model
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Hair")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="hair_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $hair;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Eyes")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="eyes_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $eyes;
```

For example, hair could be: blonde, brown, black, red;

The eyes: blue, green, gray, brown.

In the search form I want user to be able to select multiple hair types and eyes at once. I use 'multiple' property:

```
class ModelType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('hair', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => 'AppBundle:Hair',
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'multiple' => true,
            ])
            ->add('eyes', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => 'AppBundle:Eyes',
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'multiple' => true,
            ])
            ->getForm();
       ;
}
```

The form renders like this:

[image: form]

Of course, when selecting multiple values and submitting it causes an error:

```
Expected argument of type "AppBundle\Entity\Hair", "Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection" given
```

Perhaps, this is not for using in such a case?

Are any best practices for building search forms in Symfony? Didn't find any...

Comment: [Creating a combined formtype by embedding individual formtypes for one-to-many association in symfony](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/a4hv/creating-a-combined-formtype-by-embedding-individual-formtypes-for-one-to-many-association-in-symfony) and [Full webform style CRUD example with an embedded associated entity in symfony](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/djrc/full-webform-style-crud-example-with-an-embedded-associated-entity-in-symfony)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not the form but your mapping.

I assume your form is binded with the Model Entity.
That's why the ManyToOne relation accepts only one related entity.

**Solution** :

Don't bind your form to the Model Entity, just use a form without class :

http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/without_class.html

Comment: You're right. The form is binded with Model Entity, and it's not appropriate solution. The form has to be binded to some entity ONLY if it manipulates that entity. Despite the Search form operates with related entities (finds them), it's rather third-part functionality for these entities. So there shouldn't be direct mapping to it.

Answer (score 1):

Model can have many hair color and many eyes color ?

In this case you have to use `many-to-many` relation instead of `many-to-one`

If not, you have to remove `'multiple' => true,` in you `ModelType`

Comment: This is only when we want to edit the related entities. He can use the entitytype.

Comment: My answer was not suited to the problem I changed it :)

Comment: Your new answer was also my first try :). But now I see it is a search form ;) and should not be bound to the entity.

Comment: "In the SEARCH form I want user to be able to select multiple hair types and eyes at once"

Comment: Yes I just see it haha

Comment: Indeed, in this case your answer is most adapted